# Excllude all migrations from code coverage

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-6, ef-code-first, xunit

I would like to exclude all migrations from code coverage analysis automatically using some command or some configuration file.
I currently put the [ExcludeFromCodeCoverage] attribute on all migrations